# Retrieving Fillable PDF's values and use in Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am looking for a solution to import a PDF file into my HTML page and pull the filled in values from the PDF into input tags on the HTML page.

I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using pdf.js, it has some really interesting functionality https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look & get back to you ASAP